# How to mention "Optional", and "Required" fields in response model class of retrofit2 in android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

How to mention "Required" and "Optional" fields in the Response class of Retrofit2. In my case this is the response of API call

Json Class:

```
{
"id":"133544", //Required
"name":"abcd" //Optional

}
```

ModelClass :

```
public class User {


    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    }
```

How to differentiate the required and optional fields here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021699/gson-optional-and-required-fields-with-naming-policy?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Gson will set your serialized fields value to null. In your example if the JSON response you are getting `does not include a field name`, the resulting POJO will have `null` for the `name`.