# Null-safe network response using Gson and Kotlin

Tags: java, gson, kotlin, json-deserialization

Assuming you have such data-class pojo, which represents typical gson-based representation of a response which comes from a server.

```
data class User(
        @field:SerializedName("id")
        val id: String,
        @field:SerializedName("name")
        val name: String,
        @field:SerializedName("user_phone")
        val phone: String?)
```

**id** and **name** fields are required, **phone** field is optional
So the appropriate json this model expects, for example:

```
{
   "id": "someHash",
   "name": "John Snow"
}
```

Sometimes server  can send json like:

```
{
   "id": "someHash"      
}
```

Unfortunately such json is parsed successfully without any error, because gson uses *unsafe reflection* and was written for java. So as a result there will be corrupted kotlin model with **null** stored in **non-null** field

I want to provide validation for this model on the json-deserialization layer, because it is better to receive an error right there, not in any other part of application, which expects non-null field.
And i'm looking for any consize solution for this problem.

Of course you can provide some explicit validation function for each model like

```
fun User.validate() {
    if (id == null) throw JsonParseException("'id' is null!")
    if (name == null) throw JsonParseException("'name' is null!")
}
```

and call it by hand in any place but it produces a lot boilerplate code, which we always try to avoid. And also ide warns this as it thinks unnecessary null checking

Comment: Have you tired https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson?

Comment: @fisher3421 No, i haven't. Does this library have a solution for this? And if possible i want to avoid additional dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom `JsonDeserializer` that will validate fields annotated by something like `@RequiredField` and automatically throw exception if it is null.

How to do it you can find here: [Gson optional and required fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626690/gson-optional-and-required-fields)

Comment: maybe this is the only way, but of course would be better to avoid additional annotation & additional reflection in jsonDeserializers, because kotlin already has out of the box feature for nullable & non-null fields. But i do not exclude that this is the only way

Comment: @Beloo, Best way that I know - write something like this, but for Gson: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/kotlin/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/KotlinJsonAdapter.kt

Comment: The old link is broken. Permalink here: https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/13a40edf5bb5779da81862d196df7ed4f944eea0/kotlin/reflect/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/kotlin/reflect/KotlinJsonAdapter.kt