# Android Gson - deserializing null vs absent values

Tags: android, gson, json-deserialization

I'd like to understand the difference with a server  returning value verses that value being completely absent in the response.

lets take at what i  have so far:

```
data class MyApiResponse(@SerializedName("name") val name: String,
                                  @SerializedName("address") val address: String,
                                  @SerializedName("max_time") val maxTime: Double? = null //this field  might  BE  COMPLETELY absent in response, what will  happen  here ? 
)
```

regarding the maxTime value, if the value is COMPLETELY absent from server response, will the app crash or will the value be null ?

the issue is im trying to distinguish between server sending

`max_time: null` vs **it being completely absent** ,how does gson handle this ?

Comment: I think it will just be null, I have a similar setup in my project where some fields are just sometimes not sent. They come as null in my POJOs. I use Java but it should be the same. Do you need to differentiate between those two states (do a different thing for null vs absent) or is it just a theoretical question?

Comment: i dont need to do anything different. i just want to know if app will crash if value is ABSENT.

Comment: It will be null in absence of the value ,and can you do try catch block? that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases it will be null.
Might look here for more info:
[Gson optional and required fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626690/gson-optional-and-required-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
    String json = ""; //Your json has a String
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();


    String name = jsonObject.get("name").toString();
    String adress = jsonObject.get("address").toString();
    //If null, use a default value
    JsonElement max_time = jsonObject.get("max_time");
    String text = (max_time instanceof JsonNull) ? "" : max_time.getAsString();




    String json = ""; //Your json has a String
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    MyApiResponse myApiResponse = gson.fromJson(json, YOURCLASSNAME.class);
```

Comment: What's your conclusion?